# How to return number of updated rows from child stored procedure to parent in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How to return number of updated rows from child stored procedure to parent in MySQL?
The child stored procedure is called from parent using a cursor.

Ex:

Stored Procedure 1 (parent):

```
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE _a, _b, _c, VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE Mogambo_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT a, b, c, FROM tblMogambo;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN Mogambo_Cursor;    
read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH Mogambo_Cursor INTO _a, _b, _c;
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    ELSE
        CALL storedProcedure2 (_a, _b, _c);
    END IF;
END LOOP;
CLOSE AdditionalConstraint_Cursor;
```

Stored Procedure 2 (child):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tblLuke (a, b, c) ....
```

The Stored Procedure 2 does not always insert a row. How can I know how many rows were updated at the end of execution of Stored Procedure 1?

I tried with @@ROW_COUNT and using a variable but was unable to get the expected result. Is there any way to get the updated rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE _a, _b, _c, VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE total_count NUMBER DEFAULT 0; <- declare new var total_count
DECLARE Mogambo_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT a, b, c, FROM tblMogambo;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN Mogambo_Cursor;    
read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH Mogambo_Cursor INTO _a, _b, _c;
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    ELSE
        CALL storedProcedure2 (_a, _b, _c,_outParameter);
        total_count :=total_count+_outParameter
    END IF;
    SELECT total_count FROM DUAL;
END LOOP;
CLOSE AdditionalConstraint_Cursor;
```

As shown in above code you may declare one out parameter for child procedure and getting that outparameter's value you can calculate total row inserted by given procedure1.
You have to declare one more variable to get final total updated rows value as total_count given in above code.
And that value you can get in any form like out variable or just simply print using select from dual.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I did the following as suggested also I added the line in SP1
DECLARE _outParameter INT;

And in SP2, I added the following:
OUT outParameter INT in parameter list
and finally SET outParameter = ROW_COUNT();

Still getting the output -1. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In child procedure after insert or update just put commit and then try to get value of `ROW_COUNT()` in procedure2.
If this returns proper answer then proceed for procedure1.